# Synchronizing/merging Empathy logs and Google chat logs

Tags: empathy, log, gmail

If I use Empathy to log into my Google account and chat with people, I can enable logging and have it save chat logs to my computer.

The problem is, I don't only use one computer, so I end up with logs all over the place. I could use Dropbox or something to synchronize them, but that only works on computers I use Empathy on. I would still lose out on chat logs that I make from within Gmail or Google Plus or on my phone or anywhere else.

An ideal solution for me, as someone who only chats through my Google account, would be if Empathy would just use Google's chat log, the same one I access through Gmail. This would be used to display previous conversations when a chat window is opened, and to view chat logs in Empathy's UI.

Is this possible? I tried Googling but I couldn't even find anyone asking this question.

Comment: 12.10 beta 2 still not saving the chat log to gmail :(

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. As far as I can tell, syncing the logs with the Google account was the default behaviour until the last update. Perhaps you can make it work simply by rolling back to a previous version.